# Pass in variable for CSS3 Animation

Tags: html, css

I have a progress bar that I want to move according to the current width. I can get it to move to a static width, but I have no idea how to pass in the new width to set it to.

The CSS is

```
@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
    .checkout-bar li.active:after {
      @include green-stripe;
      @include inner-shadow;
      content:"";
      height: 15px;
      left: 50%;
      width: 0%;
      float: left;
      position: absolute;
      top: -50px;
      z-index: 0;
      -webkit-animation: myanimation 3s 0 forwards;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes myanimation {
      from {
        width: 0;
      }
      to {
        width: 50%; //I would like this to be a variable
      }
   }
```

This is the html:

```
 <div className="checkout-wrap">
    <ul className="checkout-bar">
      <li className="visited">Received Message</li>
      <li className="visited">Splitting Message</li>
      <li className="visited">Publish on Call</li>
      <li className="visited">Ready to Send</li>
      <li className="active" style={{'width': iOSPercent + '%'}}>Sending Message</li> // this should pass in the width
      <li className="next">Done</li>
   </ul>

</div>;
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Neither CSS nor HTML has any variables. Do you have access to JavaScript or CSS-based languages like SASS or LESS?

Comment: Yes. I'm writing the frontend in React, and the stylesheet is a Sass file with .scss syntax

Answer (score 0):

Use an additional child node (like a `div`) for the load animation and set the keyframe target to 100%. The child node should take the whole space of your `li` so it responds to the width you set programmatically. And of course change the CSS to target the `div` not the `li`.

Comment: How would I rewrite the animation from and to? Where am I going from and where am I going to?

Comment: your css selector could be something like: ```.checkout-bar li.active div:after``` and you always go to 100%. The div spans the whole place available in ```.checkout-bar li.active``` so adapts to your script setting the width to iOSPercent...

Comment: The problem is that I ultimately need to pass variables into the @-webkit-keyframes myanimation {from {width: 0} to { width: 50%} } selector. This is because I need to dictate how to update the animation. Passing to the other selector won't exactly accomplish that.

Comment: You don't have to pass a variable to the animation key frame. The approach is similar to the one Bootstrap is using: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress-animated - the inner element animates to 100% of its width; the width is determined by the parent. That's it...

Comment: It doesn't seem to pass the width into `.checkout-bar li.active:after` So, it never adjusts and simply goes based on the higher parameter. Thanks for all your help.